# How can I write multiline strings in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have this string literal with line breaks:

```
file :: String
file = "the first line\nthe second line\nthe third line"
```

Is there any way to write it like this?

```
file :: String
file = "the first line
        the second line
        the third line"
```

The attempt just above leads to this error:

```
factor.hs:58:33:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character '\n'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Assuming there was a way, would it not add whitespace to achieve the indentation?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can write multiline strings like so

```
x = "This is some text which we escape \
      \   and unescape to keep writing"
```

Which prints as

```
"This is some text which we escape   and unescape to keep writing"
```

If you want this to print as two lines

```
x = "This is some text which we escape \n\
      \   and unescape to keep writing"
```

Which prints as

```
This is some text which we escape
    and unescape to keep writing
```

Answer (score 50):

Some time ago I released a library named [**"neat-interpolation"**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/neat-interpolation-0.3.2.1/docs/NeatInterpolation.html) to solve the problem of multiline strings and interpolation using the `QuasiQoutes` extension. Its primary advantage over competitors is a smart management of whitespace, which takes care of interpolated multiline strings. Following is an example of how it works.

Executing the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, OverloadedStrings #-}

import NeatInterpolation (text)
import qualified Data.Text.IO

f :: Text -> Text -> Text
f a b = 
  [text|
    function(){
      function(){
        $a
      }
      return $b
    }
  |]

main = Data.Text.IO.putStrLn $ f "1" "2"
```

will produce this (notice the reduced indentation compared to how it was declared):

```
function(){
  function(){
    1
  }
  return 2
}
```

Now let's test it with multiline string parameters:

```
main = Data.Text.IO.putStrLn $ f 
  "{\n\
  \  indented line\n\
  \  indented line\n\
  \}" 
  "{\n\
  \  indented line\n\
  \  indented line\n\
  \}"
```

We get

```
function(){
  function(){
    {
      indented line
      indented line
    }
  }
  return {
    indented line
    indented line
  }
}
```

Notice how it neatly preserved the indentation levels of lines the variable placeholders were at. The standard interpolators would have messed all the whitespace and produced something like the following instead:

```
    function(){
      function(){
        {
  indented line
  indented line
}
      }
      return {
  indented line
  indented line
}
    }
```

Comment: Interesting - but doesn't work with GHC 7.4.x due to the language extensions it requires. (`MultiWayIf`, `LambdaCase`.)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yes. I don't support GHC older than 7.6 in most of my libraries.

Answer (score 31):

In Haskell you can type multiline strings by ending it with a backslash `\` and beginning the newline with another `\`, just like so :

```
file :: String
file = "the first line\n\  
    \the second line\n\  
    \the third line\n"
```

Comment: This does not add newline like the OP wants

Comment: You'll need to explicitly add the newline escape character for this to work. As you've written it this will not work.

Comment: Yeah of course, sorry. I was more focused on showing you to add multiple-line strings in Haskell that I forgot to write the '\n'.
Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. Best answer IMHO because it not only *shows* what to do but also *explains* how it works in general. Really nice.

Answer (score 25):

I don't believe that Haskell has an easy way to do this without resorting to quasiquoting or something else. However you can mostly get what you want by using the unlines function like below. However this will result in a newline after your last line, which you may or may not care about.

```
file :: String
file = unlines [
    "the first line",
    "the second line",
    "the third line"
    ]
```

Comment: This has a runtime cost, which isn't the case with literals like in my or nschoe's answer

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. I did just read to core hoping that GHC would optimize away that call, but no such luck. I have seen this pattern in a few places though.

Comment: FWIW, I would say this is the most common pattern.

Comment: +1: This is probably the canonical solution. Template Haskell solves the runtime cost if said cost is even a problem in the first place. Use `intercalate "\n"` instead of `unlines` if you do not want the trailing newline.

Comment: If you're using intercalate like Thomas Eding suggests, just remember to `import Data.List`. I'm guessing the requirement of the import is why I've seen `unlines` used more often than `intercalate`.

Comment: @jozefg "premature optimisation is the root of all evil", The runtime cost is tiny and only O(1) because of laziness, if you have performance issues with this, don't use [Char], ByteString or Text is probably what to want.

Answer (score 12):

Many times this facality is referred to as heredocs. Haskell does not have heredocs.

However, there are several packages that use GHC's QuasiQuotes extensions to achieve this.

Here is one I use: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/interpolatedstring-perl6-0.9.0/docs/Text-InterpolatedString-Perl6.html

Your example would look like:

```
file = [q|
the first line
the second line
the third line
|]
```

Answer (score 9):

Quasiquotation examplete presented in [Multi-line strings in Haskell](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2014-02-06-multi-line-strings-in-haskell.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Text.RawString.QQ

multiline :: String
multiline = [r|<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Auto-generated html formated source</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</HEAD>
<BODY LINK="800080" BGCOLOR="#ffffff">
<P> </P>
<PRE>|]
```

[raw-strings-qq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/raw-strings-qq-1.1/docs/Text-RawString-QQ.html) is my favorite for the purpose yet.